# Optimally tag words within a substring with a label when starting & ending indices are provided [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, tokenize

I'm trying to format data in the CoNLL format for a NER task (this info is largely irrelevant). What I want to *optimally* accomplish is this -

**Input**:

- Text: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`
- Indices: `10 - 18` (brown fox), `35 - 42` (lazy dog)

**Desired Output**:

```
The        O
quick      O
brown      X
fox        X
jumps      O
over       O
the        O
lazy       Y
dog        Y
.          O
```

Is there a single-pass way to do this (because I have a lot of examples -- over 100k)?

Comment: Words can be redundant, so tagging has to be done via indices.

Comment: Don't know if its right but you can give a try to Trie data structure. It will help you in searching words

Comment: You got the indexes and the text?

Comment: @PatrickArtner correct. I have the text & a bunch of indexes. I need to split the text by tokens and tag them individually but the ones that fall under the indexes have be tagged accordingly.

Comment: What [mre] did you write to get what you want? Where is your problem with your code? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Revised input

Input :

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
s = s.replace(".","")
tag_indices = { "X" : [[10,18], [20, 25]], "Y" : [[35, 42]]}
```

Add a normal tag for the other words

```
normal_tag = "O"
```

Now for all the words in the sentence, first tag it with `normal_tag`

```
words = s.split(" ")
tagged_words = {w:normal_tag for w in words}
```

Now go through each tag and indices in the input `tag_indices`. For every `(start, end)` in the indices, slice the input string to get a `substring`.

For each word in this substring, tag it appropriately.

```
for tag,indices in tag_indices.items():
    for start,end in indices:
        substring = s[start:end+1]
        for word in substring.split(" "):
            if len(word)>0:
                tagged_words[word] = tag
```

The final output is in the `tagged_words` dictionary

```
for k,v in tagged_words.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output :

```
The O
quick O
brown X
fox X
jumps X
over O
the O
lazy Y
dog Y
```

Comment: You're assuming # of indices = # tags, that isn't correct. I guess I should've clarified. # of tags are fixed (at 3), but the # of indices are not.

Comment: How would you know which index gets which tag?

Comment: That is conditional. The indices are provided as -- {
"X" : [[10,18], [20, 25]],
"Y" : [[35, 42]],
"Z": [[num, num]...]
}

Comment: So you can have an arbitrary # of substrings (index pairs) associated with a particular tag. All words under those index pairs need to be tagged with their appropriate tag (key-value).